# POINTER keyword in FORTRAN equivalent in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, fortran

I came across to the following:

```
POINTER(A,B(*)) ;INTEGER B
```

What is the **C/C++ equivalent** of the above code?

What is `;INTEGER B` at the end?

Comment: Can't say anything about the first, it looks like an incomplete statement to me. The `;` just ends the current command, and starts a new one. So it is declaring a variable `B` of type integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the above [page](https://www.sharcnet.ca/help/index.php/Using_CRAY_POINTERS_in_a_FORTRAN_90_PROGRAM), the correspondence between Cray pointer and C pointer may be something like this (note, however, that Cray pointer is not the same as standardized pointer in modern Fortran).

Fortran:

```
integer    a( 3 ), i
integer*8  ptr
pointer( ptr, b(*) ); integer b

a(:) = 10
print *, "a = ", a( 1:3 )

ptr = loc( a(1) )    !! now b(i) becomes an alias of a(i) for i=1,2,3
b( 2 ) = 30

print *, "b = ", b( 1:3 )
print *, "a = ", a( 1:3 )
```

C:

```
int i, a[ 3 ] = { 10, 10, 10 };
int *ptr, *b;

printf( "a = %d %d %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2] );

ptr = &( a[0] );   // <--> ptr = loc( a(1) ) in Fortran
b = ptr;           // <--> pointer( ptr, b(*) ) in Fortran

b[ 1 ] = 30;

printf( "b = %d %d %d\n", b[0], b[1], b[2] );
printf( "a = %d %d %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2] );
```

Compile

```
gfortran -fcray-pointer test.f90
gcc test.c

a = 10 10 10
b = 10 30 10
a = 10 30 10
```

Answer (score 3):

As the comments correctly say the first half is a (non-standard) cray pointer construct, after the semi-colon is a simple declaration; this is a really bizarre mix of programming ages!

More info on Cray Pointers can be found at

https://www.sharcnet.ca/help/index.php/Using_CRAY_POINTERS_in_a_FORTRAN_90_PROGRAM

Comment: What is the equivalent?